# How to call use Kafka transactional producer from a microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-producer-api, transactional

I am building an enterprise event scheduler based on Kafka streams. The scheduled events are collected or generated from microservices in the cloud. Each microservice will have about 200 worker threads to handle user requests with throughput over 10K TPS. Each request will generate an event that will be triggered in the future and the event needs to be published to Kafka for streams processing with exact-once semantics. I can find a lot of examples on the Internet that sends many records in a loop between beginTransaction and commitTransaction for the producer. In my case, there are about 200 threads that generate events and I don't think it is right to start a new transaction per message. My current solution is to create a BlockingQueue and let all threads to push event into it and a singleton Kafka producer will periodically drain the queue and send the event to Kafka in a transaction. So far it is pretty stable but I am worried that there is no way for each request to know if the message is successfully pushed to Kafka. From an individual request perspective, it pushes the event to the blocking queue and returns to the caller immediately. If the microservice crashes, then we might lose events in the blocking queue. Another solution I am thinking of is to create a producer pool with dozens of producers created and initiated with different transaction ids; however, I think this would be very resource intensive. I am wondering if anyone has a better solution for this use case. Thanks.

Comment: If you use the `onCompletion` callbacks, then you would be able to track if messages are sent, but sounds like you're just dealing with having a stateful service in an ephemerai, microservices world

Comment: The microservice itself is stateless. The end user posts a request from a single page application to the microservice and the request needs to be published to the Kafka topic successfully to return 200 status code to the user. If failed to publish for some reasons, it needs to return 400 status code. Without waiting for the callback from Producer.send, we don't know if the sending action is done successfully or not. At this moment, I am thinking to create a producer pool with initTransaction called. Each request gets a producer from the pool and begin the transaction and commit synchronously.

Comment: When microservice dies, all the requests present in blocking queue will be lost. To guarantee 100% success, a write ahead log (WAL) on persistent storage will be required. Create a request id for each request incrementally and return success to client immediately the request is appended to WAL. The microservice can batch these requests and send those to Kafka. Before committing transaction, store the last request id first. So, if microservice dies and restarts again, it knows last request id committed and checks WAL to starts from there.

Comment: Adding WAL will slow down performance a bit but this is the price paid for processing requests without any loss.

Comment: WAL is necessary only if we go with batch to increase the throughput for Kafka. Given the extra IO, the throughput might be reduced at the microservices level. That is why I am looking at one transaction per request. In this case, writing to Kafka is the same as writing to a relational database.

Comment: But (most) relational databases also use WALs

Comment: In case of one transaction per request, the sender has to wait for successful transaction and retry if the transaction fails. If you are queuing requests or making batches then WAL will be required.

Comment: I understand and Kafka works the similar way. The focus is if we need an extra WAL on the microservice or not. As Ajay stated, we need a WAL if we want to batch process requests in the microservices.

Comment: I think WAL is a necessity, but consuming the queue can approached differently...
every time a client send a request, u store the message in the WAL queue in a transactional way and then send a trigger to the queueConsumer. The queueConsumer will drain the queue and send the events to kafka in a blocking call according to your semantics